# How to refactor code by calling function just one time?

Tags: java

I have the following function :

```
private Document readResponse(String pageId,String postId) throws Exception {
    String request="https://www.facebook.com/"+pageId+"/posts/"+postId+"/?
    HttpResponse hResponse;


     hResponse = hrHandler.executeGet(request, headerParameters,null, null);


                Document doc =Jsoup.parse(hResponse.getBody());

        return doc;
```

I want to use its result in the following 2 functions,which means I want to call it one time :

```
private Integer getObject1(String pageId,String postId) throws Exception {
        String[] a=null;

            Elements e=doc.getElementsByTag("script");
            Pattern p =Pattern.compile("----:(.*?(?=\\\\s\\\\w+=|$))");//\\\\d+");;


            for(Element el:e) {
            //.contains("(TimeSlice)")) {
                Matcher m = p.matcher(el.data());
                while(m.find()){
                    a=m.group().split(",");
                }


             }
            return Integer.parseInt(a[0].replace("anything :",""));    
            }

private Integer getComments1(String pageId,String postId) throws Exception {
    String[] a=null;
                Document doc =readResponse( pageId, postId);
        Elements e=doc.getElementsByTag("script");
        Pattern p =Pattern.compile("mystring1:(.*?(?=\\\\s\\\\w+=|$))");

        for(Element el:e) {
        //.contains("(TimeSlice)")) {
            Matcher m = p.matcher(el.data());
            while(m.find()){
                a=m.group().split(",");
            }


         }
        return Integer.parseInt(a[0].replace("something:",""));    
        }
```

How can I do this wihout calling the readResponse () function 2 times? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you pass Document to these two methods you can do something like this.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Document doc=readResponse("","");
        Integer i=getObject1(doc);
        Integer comments=getComments1(doc);
    }
```

and

```
private Integer getObject1(Document doc) throws Exception
private Integer getComments1(Document doc) throws Exception
```

Answer (score 0):

You could call `readResponse` from outside of these two methods, not inside.  You'd need to change each method to take the `Document` as a parameter, instead of `pageId` and `postId`.  So the method signatures could look like this.

```
private Integer getObjectFromDocument(Document document) throws Exception

private Integer getCommentsFromDocument(Document document) throws Exception
```

Then when you call them, you'd write something like

```
Document document = readResponse(pageId, postId);
Integer theObject = getObjectFromDocument(document);
Integer theComments = getCommentsFromDocument(document);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want that method to get called multiple times, you may call the method in your starting method and store it in some Document variable, which you can pass as argument to all the methods that require it. You will just have to declare one additional parameter in the calling methods.